# Winforms DataGridView after cell edit still has original value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using a winforms DataGridView which is databound to a Datatable. I have one column that is editable which is a TextBox Column. I am delegating an event to the CellEndEdit event of the DataGridView

```
    private void dgvProductStocks_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try { 
            var minUnitsOnHand = int.Parse(dgvProductStocks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

But the cell value in the CellEndEdit is always the original value and not the value after I have edited the column.

Comment: did you try `CellValidating` event? EventArgs for that event has a property with new value

Comment: I imagine the value isn't committed until you trigger an Update event. Alternatively, it could be that the cell leaves Edit mode before the value is updated, have you tried using the CellValueChanged event instead?

Comment: I've tried both CellValidating and CellValueChanged. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution I need to use the EditedFormattedValue

```
var editiedValue = dgvProductStocks.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].EditedFormattedValue;
```